# Delphi XE6 - I can not send the app to the Apple Store

Tags: ios, delphi, certificate

We created our first multiplatform app compiled for iOS and now we are having trouble sending it to the Apple Store. The error shown is:

[image]

- We created a certificate on Mac as follows:

[image]

- The picture below shows how this configuration in Delphi XE6:

[image]

Already have accounts on iTunes and the Apple developer accounts ($ 99 
, 00 / year). Already configured all of them following the tutorials. I think the problem is with a digital certificate, but do not know what is. Can someone give some suggestion?

Comment: Read the messages. Note that `v1.0.0` is not the same as `1.0.0`, so you'll have to fix that too.

Comment: OK Rudy, I'll fix that too. Is this the reason for the first error?

Comment: No, it is not the reason for the first error. If I had a fix for that too, I would have posted it as an answer.

Comment: OK, now resolved by following the steps in the response posted below.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I solved the same problem, I'll leave the explanation to anyone who has the same problem.

- In the Apple developer, the Certificates tab panel, you'll have to download to your Mac both certificates.
- On a Mac, double-click on each of them and register them with the utility access to the keys.
- In your delphi in Distribution Certificate field, put the name of your certificate.

Enjoy!